# Unable to remove the selected input rows from a table

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple input tags in a table of type "checkbox". I need to remove the complete row of selected checkbox.
I am using the following function to remove the selected rows:

```
function removeSelected( tblname )
{
    var tbl = document.getElementById(tblname);
    var rowcount = tbl.rows.length;
    if (tbl.rows.length > 1)
    {
        for ( var i = 0 ; i < tbl.rows.length ; i++)
        {
            var row = tbl.rows[i];
            var chkselect =         row.cells[0].getElementByTagName("input").item(0);
            var attr =  trimString(row.cells[0].getElementByTagName("input").item(1).value);
            var attr1 = trimString(row.cells[0].getElementByTagName("input").item(2).value);
            if (chkselect.checked)
            {
                tbl.deleteRow(i);
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And My html is as below:

```
<table id="myTable" border = "0">
  <tr border = "0">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id = "checkbox" value = "hen">hen</input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type = "checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value = "cock">cock</input></td>

  </tr>
</table>
<br> 

<button onclick="removeSelected("myTable")">Try it</button>
```

When I check the "hen" checkbox it should delete the hen row and when I check "cock" it should delete the cock row. However, I am unable to delete the selected one.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have not specified your exact issue.

Comment: And what's happening? What's the problem? Also, `getElementByTagName` does **not** exist. Perhaps you meant `getElementsByTagName`?

Answer (score 0):

As `AleJuliet` said, you should fix syntax errors.
And to delete rows, you should start from the end, because the rows are shifted

```js
function removeSelected( tblname ) {
    var tbl = document.getElementById(tblname);
 for ( var i = tbl.rows.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
  checkbox = tbl.rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  if(checkbox.checked){
   tbl.deleteRow(i);
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" border = "0">
  <tr border = "0">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id = "checkbox" value = "hen">hen</input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type = "checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value = "cock">cock</input></td>

  </tr>
</table>
<br> 

<button onclick="removeSelected('myTable')">Try it</button>
```